# Angular - Trouble incrementing in array

Tags: arrays, angular, button

I've come to a problem on my Angular project. In my program, I have the user select an employee from a combo box. When that happens, the array for that employee is chosen and set to selectedEmployee. From there, in a different component, the details about the employee will be displayed from the array. Now, I've run into a problem where I need to have first, next, previous, and last buttons to iterate through the different employees and I am not sure how to do that. I've tried to mess around with some things, but I'm really stuck at this point.

Note: my array is being sorted and then displayed so I cannot just simply take the direct index of whatever was selected in the combo box because it won't be the same employee in the other component.

Here's my tracker.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-tracker',
    templateUrl: `./tracker.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css']
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[] = new Array<EmpInfo>();
    ptoData: PTOData[];
    isHidden: boolean = false;
    selectedEmployee: number = 0;

    public selectedType: string = "PTO";

    constructor(
        private empInfoService: EmpInfoService,
        private ptoDataService: PTODataService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => {
                this.empInfo = empInfo.sort((a, b) => a.LastName < b.LastName ? -1 : b.LastName < a.LastName ? 1 : 0);
            });
    }

    getPTOData(): void {
        this.ptoDataService.getPTODatas().then(
            ptoData => this.ptoData = ptoData
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
        this.getPTOData();
    }


    toggleSummary(): void {
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    }

    isNextValid() {
        if (this.selectedEmployee > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    isPreviousValid() {
        if (this.selectedEmployee < this.empInfo.length - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    nextEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee + 1;
    }

    previousEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee - 1;
    }

    firstEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = 0;
    }

    lastEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.empInfo.length - 1;
    }
}
```

my tracker.component.html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-12':isHidden === true, 'col-xs-7': isHidden !== false}">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="width:50px; height: 50px; float:right; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;margin:5px;" (click)="toggleSummary()"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

    <div class="col-xs-12 no-pad" style="padding-bottom:50px;">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
          <option selected="selected" disabled>Employee Name...</option>
          <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{i}} {{emp.EmpID}} - {{emp.FirstName}} {{emp.LastName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="PTOtype" [(ngModel)]="selectedType">
          <option selected="selected" value="PTO">PTO</option>
          <option value="etoEarned">ETO - Earned</option>
          <option value="etoUsed">ETO - Used</option>
          <option value="STDLTD">STD/LTD</option>
          <option value="Uncharged">Uncharged</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Full/Half</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Scheduled?</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>In P/R?</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
              <span class="requestText">Requests:</span>
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-bargin" style="float: right;" (click)="lastEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-step-forward fa-lrg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              <button [disabled]="!isPreviousValid()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-margin" style="float:right;" (click)="nextEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lrg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              <div class="footertext">{{selectedEmployee+1}} of {{empInfo.length}}</div>
              <button [disabled]="!isNextValid()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-margin" style="float: right;" (click)="previousEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-flip-horizontal fa-lrg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-margin" style="float: right;" (click)="firstEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-step-backward fa-lrg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let pto of ptoData">
            <ng-container *ngIf="pto.type === selectedType">
              <ng-container *ngIf="pto.EmpKey === empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey">
                <td>{{pto.date | date: 'MM/dd/y'}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.fullhalf}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.hours}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.scheduled}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.notes}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.inPR}}</td>
              </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isHidden" class="col-xs-5">
    <pto-summary [selectedEmployee]="selectedEmployee"></pto-summary>
  </div>
</div>
```

my summary.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { TrackerComponent } from './tracker.component';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-summary',
    templateUrl: `./summary.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit{

    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    @Input() selectedEmployee: number;

    timeVar = " hours";
    checkboxValue = false;

    constructor(private empInfoService: EmpInfoService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => {
                this.empInfo = empInfo.sort((a, b) => a.LastName < b.LastName ? -1 : b.LastName < a.LastName ? 1 : 0);
            });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
    }

    changeTime(): void {
        if (!this.checkboxValue)
        {
            this.timeVar = " hours"

            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].STDLTD = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].STDLTD * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].Uncharged = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].Uncharged * 8;

            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBase = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBase * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOCarry = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOCarry * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBorrowed = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBorrowed * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBalance = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBalance * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORequests * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORemaining * 8;

            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETOEarned = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETOEarned * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORequests * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORemaining * 8;
        }
        else
        {
            this.timeVar = " days"

            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].STDLTD = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].STDLTD / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].Uncharged = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].Uncharged / 8;

            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBase = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBase / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOCarry = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOCarry / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBorrowed = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBorrowed / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBalance = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTOBalance / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORequests / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].PTORemaining / 8;

            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETOEarned = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETOEarned / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORequests / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].ETORemaining / 8;
        }
    }
}
```

and my summary.component.html

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">{{empInfo[selectedEmployee].LastName | uppercase}} Summary</h3>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue" (change)="changeTime()" type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
          <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
          <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Status </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <select class="form-control" id="empStatus" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpStat" name="empStatus">
                <option value="Current">Current</option>
                <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Anniversary </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAnniversary" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].Anniversary" name="empAnniversary" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">years</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Start Date </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empStartDate" [ngModel]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].StartDate | date: 'MM/dd/y'" name="empStartDate"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Adjusted Start </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAdjustedStart" [ngModel]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].AdjustedStart | date: 'MM/dd/y'" name="empAdjustedStart"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> STD/LTD </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empSTDLTD" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].STDLTD" name="empSTDLTD" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Uncharged </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empUncharged" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].Uncharged" name="empUncharged" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset>

        <h4>PTO</h4>
        <br />

        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-2"> Base </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBase" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOBase" name="ptoBase" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#43; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Carryover </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoCarry" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOCarry" name="ptoCarry" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOBalance" name="ptoBalance" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Borrowed </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBorrowed" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOBorrowed" name="ptoBorrowed" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoRequests" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTORequests" name="ptoRequests" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOBalance" name="ptoBalance" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoRemaining" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTORemaining" name="ptoRemaining" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset>

        <h4>ETO</h4>
        <br />

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
              <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Earned </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoEarned" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].ETOEarned" name="etoEarned" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
              <label class="col-xs-2"> &#8213; </label>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoRequests" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].ETORequests" name="etoRequests" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
              <label class="col-xs-2"> &#61; </label>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoRemaining" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].ETORemaining" name="etoRemaining" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6"></div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT - Updated Code**

Now, everything works except for whenever I go to the summary tab, I'm getting an error in the browser that says "Cannot read property '...' of undefined" where the '...' is the index of whichever employee is selected.

Comment: Just sort the array either in the service or when you resolve the promise from the service, so you can use the index. What's the problem with that? Also, you `isPreviousValid()` and `isNextValid()` looks a bit wrong, you should review those.

Comment: I was unaware that I could sort the array in the service. Would I just move my pipe to the service?

Comment: No - pipes are only for templates. To sort it in the service, you use plain javascript to sort it before you return the list. Or in `getEmpInfo()`, right above the line `this.empInfo = empInfo;`

Comment: Try just removing the pipe and add this where you set the array: `this.empInfo = empInfo.sort((a, b) => a.LastName > b.LastName ? -1 : b.LastName > a.LastName ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: that worked great! thanks! if you want to put that as an answer, I'll give you credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sorting the array in the template with a pipe, do the sorting in the component code when you get the data from the service. Try removing the `orderByLast`pipe in the template and modify the `getEmpInfo()` function like this:

```
getEmpInfo(): void {
   this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
       empInfo => {
           this.empInfo = empInfo.sort((a, b) => 
                a.LastName > b.LastName ? -1 : b.LastName > a.LastName ? 1 : 0);
   });
}
```

This will allow you do use the `index` from the dropdown to select your employee.

Comment: updated my code and question, could you take a look? thanks!